# Putting json data into a variable which is used to send SMTP mail

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to send an email using smtp.sendmail() in python3, which requires a text variable to be used as the body of the email. I have a JSON dictionary which I want to loop through and put those objects into that variable in a neat way but having some issues getting it to look neat. I thought about using a list to place all the objects in and then append all the objects but it isn't looking at all how I would like it to.

Is there a better way of solving this issue or is using a list a good idea but I'm just not implementing it correctly?

The email should be formatted as follows:

Device: *device name* 
Status: *status* 
Downtime: *value* 
Sensor: *sensor name*

Email code below:

```
message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(subj, TEXT)

        smtp.sendMail(message)
```

Looping code is:

```
    for x in range(len(filtered_json)):

            TEXT.append("DEVICE: " + filtered_json[x]['device'] + "\\nSTATUS: " +  filtered_json[x]['status'] + "\\nDOWNTIME: " +  filtered_json[x]['downtime'] + "\\nSENSOR: " +  filtered_json[x]['sensor'] )
```

At the moment, it is just sending the List but it looks very messy

['DEVICE: xxxx\nSTATUS: Up\nDOWNTIME: 0,0000%\nSENSOR: NetFlow V9 3', 'DEVICE: xxxxx\nSTATUS: Up\nDOWNTIME: 0,0000%\nSENSOR: NetFlow V9 3', 'DEVICE: xx\nSTATUS: Up\nDOWNTIME: 0,0000%\nSENSOR: NetFlow V9 3', 'DEVICE: xxxxxxx\nSTATUS: Up\nDOWNTIME: 0,0000%\nSENSOR: NetFlow V9 3', 'DEVICE: xxxxxxxxx\nSTATUS: Up\nDOWNTIME: 0,0000%\nSENSOR: NetFlow V9 3', 'DEVICE: xxxxxxxxxx\nSTATUS: Up\nDOWNTIME: 0,0000%\nSENSOR: NetFlow V9 3']

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you asking about? Are you asking how to make the code less messy? Are you asking how to make the email less messy? Who "requires a text variable to be used as the body of the email" – the receiver or some other part? Can you give an example what it *would* be "looking … how I would like it to"?

Comment: Hello! welcome to stack overflow
I can't help you right now because your question is a bit hard to understand. For example, you're talking about smtp email but it seems like that's not really relevant to your question. You should always reduce the problem to its absolute minimum: Can you see the problem by just printing your text variable ? Then the SMTP part is probably irrelevant and should not be part of your question.

Comment: use `"\n".join(TEXT)` to convert list to string

Comment: Hi MisterMiyagi, so the smtp function uses the variable as a text so if i send the email with the devices found then it just sends the entire array all bunched up together as shown below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `"\n".join(TEXT)` to create single string - and send this string.

```
TEXT = ['DEVICE: xxxx\nSTATUS: Up\nDOWNTIME: 0,0000%\nSENSOR: NetFlow V9 3', 'DEVICE: xxxxx\nSTATUS: Up\nDOWNTIME: 0,0000%\nSENSOR: NetFlow V9 3', 'DEVICE: xx\nSTATUS: Up\nDOWNTIME: 0,0000%\nSENSOR: NetFlow V9 3', 'DEVICE: xxxxxxx\nSTATUS: Up\nDOWNTIME: 0,0000%\nSENSOR: NetFlow V9 3', 'DEVICE: xxxxxxxxx\nSTATUS: Up\nDOWNTIME: 0,0000%\nSENSOR: NetFlow V9 3', 'DEVICE: xxxxxxxxxx\nSTATUS: Up\nDOWNTIME: 0,0000%\nSENSOR: NetFlow V9 3']

variable = "\n".join(TEXT)

print(variable)
```

Result

```
DEVICE: xxxx
STATUS: Up
DOWNTIME: 0,0000%
SENSOR: NetFlow V9 3
DEVICE: xxxxx
STATUS: Up
DOWNTIME: 0,0000%
SENSOR: NetFlow V9 3
DEVICE: xx
STATUS: Up
DOWNTIME: 0,0000%
SENSOR: NetFlow V9 3
DEVICE: xxxxxxx
STATUS: Up
DOWNTIME: 0,0000%
SENSOR: NetFlow V9 3
DEVICE: xxxxxxxxx
STATUS: Up
DOWNTIME: 0,0000%
SENSOR: NetFlow V9 3
DEVICE: xxxxxxxxxx
STATUS: Up
DOWNTIME: 0,0000%
SENSOR: NetFlow V9 3
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you need to separate devices then you can use `join()` with double `\n\n` to create empty line between devices. Or you can use `\n---\n` to create line between devices.

```
TEXT = ['DEVICE: xxxx\nSTATUS: Up\nDOWNTIME: 0,0000%\nSENSOR: NetFlow V9 3', 'DEVICE: xxxxx\nSTATUS: Up\nDOWNTIME: 0,0000%\nSENSOR: NetFlow V9 3', 'DEVICE: xx\nSTATUS: Up\nDOWNTIME: 0,0000%\nSENSOR: NetFlow V9 3', 'DEVICE: xxxxxxx\nSTATUS: Up\nDOWNTIME: 0,0000%\nSENSOR: NetFlow V9 3', 'DEVICE: xxxxxxxxx\nSTATUS: Up\nDOWNTIME: 0,0000%\nSENSOR: NetFlow V9 3', 'DEVICE: xxxxxxxxxx\nSTATUS: Up\nDOWNTIME: 0,0000%\nSENSOR: NetFlow V9 3']

variable = "\n---\n".join(TEXT)

print(variable)
```

Result

```
DEVICE: xxxx
STATUS: Up
DOWNTIME: 0,0000%
SENSOR: NetFlow V9 3
---
DEVICE: xxxxx
STATUS: Up
DOWNTIME: 0,0000%
SENSOR: NetFlow V9 3
---
DEVICE: xx
STATUS: Up
DOWNTIME: 0,0000%
SENSOR: NetFlow V9 3
---
DEVICE: xxxxxxx
STATUS: Up
DOWNTIME: 0,0000%
SENSOR: NetFlow V9 3
---
DEVICE: xxxxxxxxx
STATUS: Up
DOWNTIME: 0,0000%
SENSOR: NetFlow V9 3
---
DEVICE: xxxxxxxxxx
STATUS: Up
DOWNTIME: 0,0000%
SENSOR: NetFlow V9 3
```

Answer (score 0):

(I left a comment before)

So, after looking at your question for a while, I think I understand what you're looking for: Create multiple string with newlines in python. I believe the rest of the question is here because you were not able to reduce the issue to its essence...

I'll try to walk you though the process.

Fist, let's do a single string with a newline in it, the way you did it:

```py
print("hello \\n there")

# output:
hello \n there
```

Well, that's not good. the first backslash is telling python "treat the next character as a normal character", so it does, and prints `\` then `n`

```py
print("hello\nthere")

# output:
hello
there
```

Good! Now, let's put it in an array:

```
texts = [
  "hello\nthere",
  "bye\nthen",
]
print(texts)

# output:
['hello\nthere', 'bye\nthen']
```

Crap, we're back to square one. Except... not really.
This is the part where I have an advantage over you: Having used python quite a lot, I know that this is just how python prints arrays of strings with newlines. Let's try printing just one of the elements in the array:

```
print(texts[1])

# output:
bye
then
```

Now, if you need to print the array in a pretty way somewhere, you need to "convert" it into a string. A very common way of doing that in python is the "join" function: it joins all the elements in the array, with a character in-between.

```py
# I know the syntax is weird: The join function is not part of the array object, but the String object.
# Here, we're saying "use a comma as the glue between all the elements in the array"
",".join(["hello", "there", "general", "spagetti"])

# result:
# "hello, there, general, spagetti"
```

Now, we can put everything together:

```py
# Some fake data
data = [
  {'device': '1', 'status': 'ok', 'downtime': '3%', 'sensor': 'k'},
  {'device': '2', 'status': 'ok', 'downtime': '3%', 'sensor': 'k'},
  {'device': '3', 'status': 'stopped', 'downtime': '3%', 'sensor': 'k'},
  {'device': '4', 'status': 'stopped', 'downtime': '0%', 'sensor': 'k'},
]

# create the array where we'll put our strings
output = []

# loop over the array
for item in data:
  # 'item' represents one of the items in the data array. I could have given it any name,
  # but 'item' seems like it fits this situation quite well (always take care of
  # properly naming your variables, it makes the code 1000x easier to read)
  output.append(
    "DEVICE: " + item['device'] + "\n" +
    "STATUS: " +  item['status']  + "\n" +
    "DOWNTIME: " + item['downtime']  + "\n" +
    "SENSOR: " +  item['sensor'] )

# Here, I'm getting fancy with the separator. I could have just used
# a newline (\n), but I want the "blocks" to be clearly separated.
separator = "\n-----------------\n"
print(separator.join(output))

# output:
DEVICE: 1
STATUS: ok
DOWNTIME: 3%
SENSOR: k
-----------------
DEVICE: 2
STATUS: ok
DOWNTIME: 3%
SENSOR: k
-----------------
DEVICE: 3
STATUS: stopped
DOWNTIME: 3%
SENSOR: k
-----------------
DEVICE: 4
STATUS: stopped
DOWNTIME: 0%
SENSOR: k
```

Last tip: you might want to have a look at python f-strings. They can make your code more readable:

```
for item in data:
  output.append(f"""
DEVICE:     {item['device']}
STATUS:     {item['status']}
DOWNTIME:   {item['downtime']}
SENSOR:     {item['sensor']}
  """.strip())
  # The 'strip' function is here to remove the first and last newlines
  # The indentation above might look wrong, but it's not: since we're
  # defining a string, adding indentation there would result in indentation
  # in the string itself, which we don't want
```

Comment: Hi Bastien, that's kind of what I already have in my code. So when I print a single object, it shows it in a neat order with each key-value pair on a new line but what I actually need is to have this same format in the email text that is sent which uses the array.

So for example, when I send that array via email , it no longer looks neat and simply spits out the entire array in the email:

Comment: ['DEVICE: xxxx\nSTATUS: Up\nDOWNTIME: 0,0000%\nSENSOR: NetFlow V9 3', 'DEVICE: xxxxx\nSTATUS: Up\nDOWNTIME: 0,0000%\nSENSOR: NetFlow V9 3', 'DEVICE: xx\nSTATUS: Up\nDOWNTIME: 0,0000%\nSENSOR: NetFlow V9 3', 'DEVICE: xxxxxxx\nSTATUS: Up\nDOWNTIME: 0,0000%\nSENSOR: NetFlow V9 3', ]

Comment: Aah I see, then you need to "join" the elements of your array into a single string. I'll update my answer